# Why not create 2 foreign key to 2 tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Good morning, please tell me why not a link is created for 2 tables ? For the first is created for 2 no.

Error
In the SQL query:

```
Alter table `Shop` add foreign key (Nomerah`) references `aircraft.`The lists`(`Номер_цеха_fk`) on delete restrict on update restrict;
Answer MySQL: The Documentation

#1050 - table '.\aircraft\@I1@L0@N1@g0' already exists
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Missing begining backtick on (nomerah) and you missing close one after references aircraft(missing).the lists

Comment: I don't understand English, misunderstood you. Can be a bit of a reality ? @xQbert

Comment: Please write what did I do wrong, it is very important to me @xQbert

Comment: Ok, the nature of the error implies that the "NAME" for the foreign key already exists, have you tried a different name?

Comment: Yes, I did not help @xQbert

Comment: It works, if you enter another name here, this is correct, it will not cause an error? @xQbert http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/2017-03-14_22-27-10.1489519659.png

Comment: http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/2017-03-14_22-28-38.1489519729.png result @xQbert